# Python: Removing an Item From a List, But Returns a New List

Tags: python, list

Is there anyway to remove an item from a list in such a way that I return a new list without the removed element?

For instance,
if I have a list `['a','b','c','d','e']` (called my_list), then I would like a method that does the following `my_list.newRemove('a')` = `['b','c','d','e']`.

I want to do this in such a way that I could send the element to be removed and the new list as parameters of a function:

```
func(element, my_list.newRemove(element))
```

for example:

```
func('a', list.newRemove('a'))
```

which would pass `'a'` AND `['b','c','d','e']`

I know I can do this by just passing the element and the entire list to the function, and then creating a new subList in the function without the passed element. However, I feel like it would look better to do it the way I'm asking.

Is this just a fundamentally un-pythonic way of doing this? I learned to program with functional languages, and old habits die hard.

---

Edit: mistakenly wrote set rather than list

Edit 2: Here is an example of what I ultimately want to do:

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d']

for element in myList:
    function(element, myList.newRemove(element)
```

Where function does a calculation between the element and the rest of the elements in the list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: listcomp: `[x for x in l if x != a]` perhaps

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: this will remove all instances... The problem is a bit underspecified...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you're right. That's why you don't see any answer down there, including _not_ mine :)

Comment: You mix the terms "set" and "list".  These are two different datatypes in Python, so it would be good if you could clarify which one you mean.

Comment: What about `newList = list.copy().remove('a')`?

Comment: Maybe the OP is looking for: `lambda l, x: l.remove(x) or l`.

Comment: @timgeb: Umm.... `newList = list.copy()` then `newList.remove('a')`.  Yeah... that's what I meant.

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to name a variable `list`.  That would replace the *built-in* `list` method.

Comment: Calling it list was just a shorthand. Sorry about saying 'set'--I meant list and accidentally typed it in a hurry.

Comment: I will try doing copy().remove(). I think I could write a function to do what I'm asking, but I was wondering if there was functionality like that already built in to python. Thanks for all your quick answers guys!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def newListRemove(element, list): return element, filter(lambda x: x != element, list)

list = [1,2,3,4]
print newListRemove(2, list)
print list
```

returns

```
(2, [1, 3, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Won't this still modify the original `list`?  **EDIT**: It does: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqZQlJqbX5bqVpSf65NZXKKRqqOQo2nFpQAEmWkKqQp5@SUKmXkKOVZAhSWlRXkKfvl5IDVgFTl6EN0aqZpgPlQJWJ4rtxJkoIKtQrShjoKRjoKxjoJJLBdXQVFmXgm6rUBpiHJNqDyE9/8/AA "Python 2 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: It modifies the original list

Comment: try now, calling newListRemove instead

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way of removing an element while copying is using comprehension lists: `[x for x in my_list if x != element]`. So there is no need of a function for this. For your example:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d']

for element in my_list:
    function(element, [x for x in my_list if x != element])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean, but I'm not sure.

```
def newRemove(element, x):
    x.remove(element)
    return element, x

print(newRemove("a", ["a", "b","c", "d"]))
```

which returns:

```
('a', ['b', 'c', 'd'])
```

hope this helps.

There is no built in function to do what you are asking, you'd have to make one.

And just a little pro-tip if you are trying to find a function that you can't remember what is called or don't know if it exists, to this: Type `list.` not the list you are trying to edit but literally `list.` and hit tab, which should then bring up all of the functions that can edit a list. Most of them are self explanatory, but it is easy to figure out what they do by trial and error.

Hope this helps for all your future coding endeavors

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I don't want to change the original list, however. I think I could write a function that does what I'm asking--I was more wondering if python had something like that already built in.

Comment: @HarryBaker so your saying you want it to return `('a', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`? or do you want it to make a new list that is just `['b', 'c', 'd']`?

Comment: I just want it to return a new list with just [b,c,d]. I'm going to edit my original comment to demonstrate why I want it to do this.

Comment: @HarryBaker you just need to do `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].remove('a')` which will return `['b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Doesn't .remove actually change the original list? I want to preserve the list

Comment: @HarryBaker check my updated answer for all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
def newListRemove(element, list):
  list.remove(element)
  return list

list = [1,2,3,4]
print(removeFromList(2, list))
print(list)
```

This should be what you need.